# React - having trouble setting state of a collection through a text box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my initialized state like this:

```
this.state = {
    notearr: {
         noteid: this.props.id,
         notevalue: null,
    },
    dataLoaded: false,
};
```

And then a function to handle the textbox onChange event:

```
<TextField
    name="notevalue"
    value={this.state.notevalue}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Here is my present onChange handler:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.notearr.notevalue);
};
```

In the handleChange function, I would like to target the notearr collection, but am unsure how to target that specific collection. It currently writes to the root of the state, rather within the desired collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to override `notearr` with a new object, that you clone from the previous state:

```
 const { name, value } = event.target;
 this.setState(prev => ({ notearr: { ...prev.notearr, [name]: value }}));
```

You might be tempted to do this instead:

```
 this.setState({ notearr: { ...this.state.notearr, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }});
```

... however with that version, if two updates happen at the same time they will override each other, as `setState` is asynchronous. Also as events get recycled you need to copy the values over before the callback.

Also note that logging `this.state` after calling `setState` will not show you the updated state as `setState` is asynchronous. If you are seeing the updated state there, you're doing something wrong (you're mutating state).

Comment: Thanks, Jonas! I'm having an error with this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null. Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event.

Comment: Perfection! I see it also works with event.persist(); but I like your solution better! Thanks so much for your help!